# Intermediate field extensions and Degree of field extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I was wondering whether there is a relation between $[L:K]$ and the number of intermediate fields $F$, where $K\subseteq F\subseteq L$. If there is then can someone please explain why. What if $L/K$ was Galois, would that make a difference to whether a relation exists or not.

Comment: Is $L|K$ Galois?

Comment: I'll edit my question to include both cases for when L/K is Galois or not.

Comment: Well, I know this theorem which states that "A **finite extension** $L|K$ is simple iff there are finite number of intermediate fields"

Comment: In the case of finite Galois extensions, your question is equivalent (since every finite group is the Galois group of some extension) to: is there a relationship between the number of subgroups of a finite group and the number of elements of the group? Considering groups of order $p^n$ with $p$ prime shows that these two numbers do not determine each other.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez If $|G|=n$, there will be $<m$ distinct subgroups **(?)** where $$m=\sum_{d|n} 1$$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: You should make this to an answer  (IMO).

Comment: I think that they might be equivalent, i.e. $[L:K]$=number of intermediate fields. The field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta , \sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree equal to 6, and the number of subfields between $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta , \sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is 6. Where $\zeta$ is the cube root of unity

Comment: maybe I can use the fundamental theorem of Galois to show some equivalence

Comment: @AndrewBrick, my comment quite directly implies that that is not the case. Forma trivial example, consider an extension of prime degree.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi, that is not the number of subgroups of a group of order $n$ ---it does work if $G$ is cyclic, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the special case of an finite extension $L/K$ which is Galois with Galois group $G$, there is a bijection between the set of the subgroups of $G$ and the set of the subfields of $L$ containing $K$. This makes it easy to see that the degree of the extension $L/K$ and the number of subfields of $L$ containing $K$ do not determine each other.

For example, if $p$ is a prime and $n\geq1$, there exists Galois extensions $L/K$ of group $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, which have degree $p^n$ and have $\phi(p^n)=p^{n-1}(p-1)$ subextensions, and there exist Galois extensions $L/K$ of group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^n$, which have degree $p^n$ and $$\dfrac{(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\cdots(p^n-p^{k-1})}{(p^k-1)(p^k-p)\cdots(p^k-p^{k-1})}$$ subextensions. In fact, there are many, many non-isomorphic groups of order $p^n$, and one probably gets a lot of different numbers of subgroups.

Comment: Urgh. The fraction is wrong. Ill fix it later...